# Django template value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, django-templates, django-views

I have passed a variable(list of dictionary) to template in django. I need that variable in java script. How can I get the variable as list without using `json.dumps` in django views.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dictionary in django say `myObj`, you may simply put this kind of *dynamic* javascript substitution to use that in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var obj = "{{myObj}}"
</script>
```

Cheers!

Comment: But 'obj' is string right? I want it as array variable. Is there any option to convert?

Comment: you may later do `JSON.parse(obj)` to get the object equivalent to python's dictionary